What happens when a user dies?
I'm not expecting the moderators to tell me about the afterlife. ;-) I do want to know if there is a policy about what happens to a user's posts if the moderators learn of the person's death.

Nothing happens to their posts. Someone might post a tribute on meta.

@curiousdannii If there is no activity in an account, is there a time when, eventually, the system will close the account ?

No, that won't happen.

I think the biggest challenge with this is knowing when a user passes away.

One user of CSE, with the pen-name Affable Geek passed away a few years back, and someone posted a note to that effect on his Profile. His posts still earn scores, which is heartening to see.
